# Four balls with different colors in a box, how many times do I need to pick to see all four colors?

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

I have one white ball, one yellow ball, one red ball, one black ball. I put the four balls in a nontransparent box. I pick a ball from the box to see its color and put it back to the box.

Assuming picking is random, how many times on average do I need to pick in order to see all four colors?

If I'm lucky, I only need to pick four times. If I'm out of luck, I may get red, red, red, red, red, red,....

But what is it on average?

Comment: mathematical boxes are always non-transparent for future reference

Comment: @JorgeFernández Also, the colors white, yellow, red, and black exist only on the balls in the box, nowhere else. You cannot "see all four colors" unless you see all four balls.

Comment: lol, I had assumed that part.

Comment: Wait, did you not see the balls as you were putting them in the box? If not, how do you know what color they are?

Comment: `If I'm out of luck, I may get red, red, red, red, red, red,....` If such a sequence continues long enough, it'll really mess up an 'average'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is known as the [coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

The *average* number of tries needed to see each of 4 colors is
$$ \frac44+\frac43+\frac42+\frac41 = 8\frac{1}{3} $$

The terms are $4/4$ for the time to take one ball; then $4/3$ for the average time it takes *after* the first ball until you see another code; $4/2$ for the average time it takes after the first time you see the second color until you see a third, and finally $4/1$ for the time you then have to wait until you see the last color. (These can just be added due to the *additivity of expectations*).

Comment: It is interesting to notice that by putting together this proof and mine, we get a nice identity for $n H_n$ involving sign-alternating binomial coefficients.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the name of the problem. Give me some time to understand the solution.

Comment: Same result as the other three answers, but so much more intuitive

Comment: That the average number of tries needed to hit one out of $k$ (remaining) among $n$ equal $n/k$ follows from solving a simple equation. But can it also be deduced from some form of additivity of expectations?

Comment: @Marc: The reference to additivity was for adding the fractions, not for finding them. (In hindsight I'm not sure whether is muddies matters more than it clarifies).

Answer (score 3):

Denote by $E(n)$ the expected number of additional draws when $n$ of the four balls have not been drawn so far. Then $E(0)=0$, and
$$E(n)=1+{n\over4} E(n-1)+{4-n\over 4}E(n)\qquad(n\geq1)\ .$$
This immediately implies
$$E(n)=E(n-1)+{4\over n}\qquad(n\geq1)\ ,$$
from which we get $E(4)={25\over3}$ by going through the motions.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, we stop picking when we take a ball having a color that never occurred before, so we have to count how many strings of length $n$ have only occurrences of $A,B,C$ (no $D$), with at least one occurence of $A$, at least one occurrence of $B$, at least one occurrence of $C$. By the inclusion-exclusion principle, they are:
$$ 3^n - 3\cdot 2^n + 3$$
so the wanted expected value is:
$$ \sum_{n=4}^{+\infty}\frac{4n}{4^n}\left(3^{n-1}-3\cdot 2^{n-1}+3\right)=\color{red}{\frac{25}{3}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

What is the probability you see all colors after exactly $n$ turns, how many sequences of length $n-1$ contain exactly three colors? first select the three colors in $4$ ways.

When using three colors there are $3^{n-1}$ sequences.

$3\cdot2^{n-1}-3$  use $2$ or $1$ colors.

Therefore $3^{n-1}-3\cdot2^{n-1}+3=3(3^{n-2}-2^{n-1}+1)$ use exactly three colors when those three colors are fixed.

Therefore there are $12(3^{n-2}-2^{n-1}+1)$ sequences.

Then the probability you see three colors for the first time in the $n$'th draw is $\frac{1}{4}\frac{12(3^{n-2}-2^{n-1}+1)}{4^{n-1}}=3\frac{(3^{n-2}-2^{n-1}+1)}{4^{n-1}}$.

Hence  you want  $3(\frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty (n+2)\frac{3}{4}^n-\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty (n+1)\frac{1}{2}^n+\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty\frac{n+1}{4^n})=3(\frac{63}{16}-\frac{5}{4}+\frac{13}{144})=\frac{25}{3}$